# TeamViewer, UNC, or mapped network drive

Tags: networking, security, lan, file-transfer

Teamviewer, UNC, mapped network drive. What's the most secure of these methods of file transfer within a LAN? I am looking to prevent the possibility of ransomware while also having efficient file transfers and minimal local resources being used. I am running an OPNsense firewall, Nord VPN and Nord Pass on all local machines.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "What's the most secure". Security is relative. What is secure enough for you? Furthermore, you are asking about LAN, but in regards to randsomware your entire network can be regarded as compromised if one of the computers should be attacked. Whatever file share method you are using at that point is not going to make a difference.

Comment: I guess I'm asking are there inherent risks/backdoor associated with any of these methods and is there a way to protect against specific attacks on file-sharing protocol

Comment: Any tool might have unknown vulnerabilities.